# Search defined row for a string, return value 2 columns to the right of located string

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, match, spreadsheet

I'm using google sheets, and trying to look up the string value in cell A2, check row 2 of Sheet2 for matching string, then (once found) return the value in the cell 2 columns to the right of the found string.

=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$2,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$2,2))

I thought this would work, but it unfortunately does not. Nor do my other attempts.

I've tried a variety of googled suggestions, but most seem to show a vertical column being searched rather than a horizontal row, and/or return a value in a known/fixed column, rather than a relative one.

Sheet here with example, feel free to edit;
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZtgrCepZivt7AHH6ShC3SQOXWKUqmzl5qickPE9O93c/edit?usp=sharing

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Edit:
Suggestion worked great. What if I were to return the value 2 columns to the right, and 2 rows below the matched value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?. Puting a 1 to indicate that's in the same row and adding 2 to the value of MATCH:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$2,1,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$2,0)+2)`

Comment: What if I were looking to return the value 2 cells to the right, and 1 row below the MATCH value?

Comment: `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$3:$3,1,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$2,0)-2)` or `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$3,2,MATCH($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$2,0)-2)`

Comment: Amazing, thank you Martín! I see now, the first sheet range next to index is the row value to return after the Match is found, and the +2/-2 is the column to return a value from.

Excellent! Thank you so much !